# React: how to get date from AG Grid row data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid-react

Description: I'm trying to format the **dateTime** I get from an **Activity** data array. I'm certain the tabular data isn't empty or nullish since I've been using a different table library on which it displays.

Problem: The page displaying my activity list table crashes as it can not find a defined date in the data I've given it. This is likely due to me not guessing the data type of the `valueGetter()` when I define columns. The documentation and tutorial I've found were in javascript, so I couldn't get the answer from them.

Here's the **ActivityModel** interface:

```
export interface ActivityModel extends obj {
  id: string
  key: string
  title: string
  description: string
  dateTime: Timestamp
  duration: number
  notes: string
  type: string
  activity: string
  completed: boolean
  material: string
  size: string
  assignedTo: string
  value: string
  unit: string
  editable: boolean
}
```

And here's the **Activities** page:

```
const [columnDefs] = useState([
        { field: "title", headerName: "Title", filter: "agTextColumnFilter" },
        {
          field: "description",
          headerName: "Description",
          flex: 3,
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
        },
        {
          field: "startDate",
          headerName: "Start Date",
          flex: 2,
          filter: "agDateColumnFilter",
          valueGetter: (p: ActivityModel) => {
            return formatDate(p.dateTime.toDate())
          },
        },
        {
          field: "completed",
          headerName: "Completed",
          filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
        },
      ])

    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 1200 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowData={activities}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        onGridReady={pullActivities}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is correct but, isn't it supposed to be like this?

```js
valueGetter: (p: ActivityModel) => {
    return formatDate(p.dateTime.toDate())
},
```

to

```js
valueGetter: (p: ValueGetterParams) => {
    return formatDate(p.data.dateTime.toDate())
},
```